# Having both cython compiled .so and source .py in the same folder.

Tags: python, cython

Is it possible to include both .so (cython compiled) and .py files in a folder with same name. Which one will python use if I use import ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but one way to find out would be to compile with cython, then change the python completely and import. so make your python version just raise an error immediately, import and if you get the error, you imported python.

Comment: It does work, with the so module loaded first. It has to do with the order of `imp.get_suffixes` (called something different in Python 3.3+). However I can't find any good reference for it right now. I'll post an answer if I can find a reference...